# Identification 16-pin IC from a 12 V Lavazza 500 coffee machine

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

[image][image][image]

[image]

Please help me identify the IC with top marking “GR”.

This is a PCB from a 12 V Lavazza 500 espresso experience coffee machine.

[image]

Comment: From watching a video of the coffee maker -- it has timing, flashing LEDs, beeping -- this is almost certainly a microcontroller.  It may well be ready-programmed, and the marking is a manufacturer's internal code.  It might be a standard processor, but it will be difficult to work out.  You could start by tracing out the circuit and trying to identify IO pins.  Are you asking for curiosity, or trying to repair one, or some other reason?

Comment: I have about 10 pcs. for repair, this board in the picture is working. Will it be possible to read and write the microcontroller?
Any idea what to use.
Thanks

Comment: @TomaNikolov You probably won't be able to dump the MCU easily. First you would have to find out what this MCU is or at least how it is programmed. Then you would have to hope that programming isn't disabled or protected in some way which is unlikely. Given the generic marking I doubt it's a well known manufacturer, it's probably a cheapo Chinese 8 bit micro which means a datasheet will be hard to find.

Comment: I don't expect an MCU failure here. Did you check the relays? You could swap the ICs of a bad and a working PCB to verify the theory.

Comment: Tthank you all for the advice you gave. it's definitely the chip because when I exchange it with a working one and everything starts normally. I don't have any experience with microcontrollers.

Comment: I think to use logic analyzer. Is it a good idea ? I will be glad for your opinion

Comment: If you trace out the rest of the circuit you may well find it's a straightfoward interfacing ... and you might be able to work out what it's supposed to do and recreate it.  Tricky to reverse the sequencing but might work.  You probably don't need a logic analyser as it's quite likely to be slow (driving pumps and so on) and might be able to do it with just an ordinary scope.

Comment: @jonathanjo Thank you so much.By the way I found another number under the chip if that helps.

Comment: @TomaNikolov can you post a good high-resolution photo of the top (without yellow box) and of the bottom?  I couldn't tell anything from the numbers on the bottom of the chip.

Comment: @ jonathanjo I hope the pictures are clear enough..
I will pray these days to a friend (professional photographer) for better ones

Comment: From your schematic it looks like a buffer chip such as a member of the ULN200x family. Possibly a ULN2003 or ULN2003.

Comment: I don't know why my photos were removed?
@jonathanjo How can I send you pictures?

Comment: @Gil I will try your idea

Comment: @TomaNikolov It's not a buffer chip, it's definitely a MCU. Gil is confused because you chose a random part as placeholder in your schematic.

Comment: @TomaNikolov Can you measure what pins R13, R7, R6 and R18 are connected to?

Comment: @nanash1 R13-pin3,R7-pin5,R6-pin2 and R18-pin12

Answer (score 3):

This is not really answer, but an extended comment. I doubt the question as it stands has a realistic chance of being answered. From your comments, I understand, your plan is to find out what IC the one in the SOP16 package is and then buy a replacement to fix this coffee maker. I don't think this will work and here is why:

First, as others have commented, it's a MCU. SOP16 is a pretty big package by modern standards. It offers a lot of real estate for markings and most manufacturers (even cheap Chinese ones) will use it to write the full product code, a logo and lot numbers/date codes. The fact that this one is marked only with two letters tells us that this is probably not an off the self product, but likely in some way customized. This means that finding out what it is from the information given is exceedingly unlikely.

I traced out the circuit (purely visual trace, no grantee), so you can check what the connections are, but I couldn't find anything compatible when searching for the markings.

[image]

But even if you manage to find out what exactly this MCU is, you're not really any further in repairing it, because you would need to dump the firmware from a working unit and flash it to your replacement. This is not really practical. The only realistic way to replace this MCU (apart from donor boards of course) is a making a functional replacement. This means you have to reverse engineer the functions of this MCU and then write your own firmware for a 5V MCU of your choosing. This is not easy for a beginner and will take a lot of work, but the functions here are probably not too complicated. When the user presses start, it runs the pump and the heater until a certain temperature is reached. Then it beeps to let the user know the espresso is ready.

Comment: Very nice work on the diagram.

Comment: @nanash1 first of all kudos for a job well done.thanks a lot!!
I will be very happy if you contact me toma_nikolov@yahoo.com

Comment: @jonathanjo many thanks

Comment: I completely agree with nanash1's comments about how it's not easy for a beginner.  It might just be possible to make a pin-compatible functional replacement with pretty much any microcontroller on some kind of carrier board.  But I notice that Microchip's 14-pin microcontrollers eg 16F256 might just possibly be able to fit right onto the footprint, with MCU pin 1 on pin 2 of the PCB.  You'd have to get power to PCB pin 15, which appears unused.  This definitely would be uneconomic in development time, but if you wanted an educational project some people would consider it fun.

Comment: @jonathanjo Will this one be suitable STC 15FW204S 8-Bit 8051 MCU 8-13.5MHz 4KB FLASH SOP-16

Comment: @TomaNikolov You should stick to well known brands with good support like Microchip, ST or NXP. The obvious choice for something like this would be a PIC or AVR 8 bit MCU.

Comment: @nanash1 Would you agree to implement the project for a fee? I can send you a working board if needed. The goal is to have 15-20 pieces to replace the defective microcontroller in the future. I contacted the manufacturer and they told me that they do not keep spare boards for this model already

Comment: @TomaNikolov do you know what's causing the microcontrollers to fail?  Regarding STC microntroller: I'd definitely try to pick something like PIC or AVR 8-bit which have very widespread support, exactly as nanash says.  I'd only consider something more unusual if magically I found one which was pin-compatible.

Comment: @jonathanjo I'm thinking about a QFN package ,make pcb and placing a sop16pin.But the problem with the firmware of the microcontroller  remains . If someone helps for a fee I will be very happy.

Comment: @TomaNikolov this is not the place to solicit proposals on this sort of thing, and regardless, I don't expect you would be able to get this done for <$10k.

Comment: @TomaNikolov You'll get a long way if you can characterise the behaviour pretty tightly: for example, how does it behave with what kinds of button pushes?  What voltages do you see at what temperatures?

Comment: @nanash1 By the way which software are you using for the schematic

Comment: @TomaNikolov [KiCad](https://www.kicad.org/), it allows you to import pictures into the PCB view for easy reverse engineering.

Comment: What I found today. I put 12V on the board I measured the voltage on pin 1-0V, pin 2-5V, pin 3-0V, pin 4-3.7V, pin 5-4.5V, pin 6-5V, pin 7-4.8V, pin8-0V, pin9-4.87V pin10-0V, pin11-5V, pin12-0V, pin13-5V, pin14,15,16-0V. The temperature sensor has 5V. There is no power to the motor and the heater. After pressing the button, there is power on the motor and the heater, after about 3 minutes, there are three rings, a signal that I have to start the coffee... there is power to the temperature sensor

Comment: motor, heater, after another 1 minute, the power to the motor and the heater stops.
I'm getting confused..very simple logic for microcontroller..I don’t know..

Comment: Most modern microcontrollers block reading of the firmware through anti-piracy prevention. In that case you'll have to erase the program before you can upload a new one.

Comment: @Lundin I completely agree with you. I am trying to repair these boards, not to produce such coffee machines. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @nanash1 Thank you very much for the attention and time you spent on my problem.
The offer remains.…

Comment: @ jonathanjo Thanks for the comments (not least)!

Comment: @ flaviut I have <$10k for the next project, would you be interested? Thanks in advance.